# Magento2 - Cron Job not working

Tags: magento2, cron

Cron Job is not working. Below is `crontab.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="index">
        <job instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Run" method="execute" name="OrdSendMail">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Comment: Code seems ok. what  Check rest of file

Answer (score 0):

for some reason after upgrade from 2.3.3 to 2.3.4 cron stopped working
All files and configurations were OK. So after many cups of coffee. This is what it worked for me

A) remove the Magento crontab:

- Log in as or switch to the Magento file system owner.
- Change to the Magento installation directory.
- Enter the following command:

  $ **bin/magento cron:remove**
  B) Change to the /var directory.

  Remove the following files:

  **.setup_cronjob_status**
  **.update_cronjob_status**

any other file related to **cron** in this folder

C) So far magento now, does not have any cron job available nor any file attached to it

Now we create a new Magento crontab:

$ bin/magento cache:flush
$ bin/magento cron:install  [Note you can use -f or --force but since we deleted is not necessary]

Now we check
$ crontab -l

It should show like

MAGENTO START c5f9e5ed71cceaabc4d4fd9b3e827a2b
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log

MAGENTO END c5f9e5ed71cceaabc4d4fd9b3e827a2b

And now we run cron

$bin/magento cron:run

Now for those who do not like or does not have experience checking DB Tables (cron_schedule) table

The easiest way is goring to backend of magento

Admin->System->Index Management

It should be SET as
UPDATE BY SCHEDULE and
READY

If it works just Refresh the page 1 minute later and the Updated Date and time should change

Good Luck

PS: part was taking from [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)